# Guru Meditation Error: [...] (LoadProhibited) esp-idf

Tags: c++, esp32, esp-idf

i am trying to implement .ino file in esp-idf project.

I have only take .ino file that works, renamed in c++ and I repositioned the methods correctly. I've changed something to remove all errors, but now i have this error in while(), when I debug `fstFrame->nxt`

Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic' ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled

That's the code:

```
while ( fstFrame->nxt ) {
        printf("\n\nin while cache\n\n");
        frameChunck* f = (frameChunck*) fstFrame->nxt;
        free ( fstFrame->dat );
        free ( fstFrame );
        fstFrame = f;
      }
```

the declaration are:

```
frameChunck *fstFrame;  // first frame
```

and

```
struct frameChunck {
  uint8_t   cnt;  // served to clients counter. when equal to number of active clients, could be deleted
  uint32_t *nxt;  // next chunck
  uint32_t  fnm;  // frame number
  uint32_t  siz;  // frame size
  uint8_t *dat;  // frame pointer
};
```

Comment: You should almost certainly be testing `fstFrame->nxt` for `NULL` before you dereference it, but it's really impossible to suggest more than that without a [minimal, reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example that demonstrates the problem. Please edit the question to include the smallest complete program that causes this crash.

Comment: @romkey Well, he is checking if nxt is null, but he shoulld really be checking fstFrame itself.

Comment: @NeilButterworth you are totally right, sorry about that.